# Discord.js how to use await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord, discord.js

I want to use await but I don't know how to. I've only been using js for 3 months now and I don't know much about functions.

Here's my code

```js
switch (args[1]) {
 case 'instagram':
  const accname = args[2];

  if (!accname) {
   return msg.reply('Include an Instagram handle');
  }

  const url = `https://instagram.com/${accname}/?__a=1`;
  const accinfo = await fetch(url).then((url) => url.json());

  console.log(accinfo);
  break;
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```js
const accinfo = await fetch(url).then(url => url.json());
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

How do I get async as a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify that your `function` is an `async function`

For example, if you are executing this code within the `discord.js` `message` event:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
   // your code...
```

---

Further examples:

```js
const log = () => {
  await console.log('This will return an error')
};

log()
```

```js
log = async() => {
  //  ^^^^^
  await console.log('However this, will not')
};

log()
```

You can view the `async / await` page from the official `discord.js` guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#understanding-async-await)